# Dynamic Context Menu using ui.bootstrap.contextMenu

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using 'ui.bootstrap.contextMenu' to build a context menu. When I right click a field, I need to pass in a unique ID, to the controller, and return a list of choices based on the ID. Each list could be different. If I use hardcoded list, it works fine, but I can't seem to generate the list dynamically. What am I missing? Example Code:

```
`<div>
    <textarea ng-model="ctrl.status" context-menu="ctrl.menuOptions (ctrl.id)"></div>
</div>
vm.menuOptions = function(id) = {
    var listArray = $scope.list; // array of possible list items based on ID 
   angular.forEach(listArray, function(value, key) {
     if (id === value.id) {
        return [ 
             [value.id, function ($itemScope) { 
                 return value.textName; 
             }],                 
        ]
     }
   }     
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're referring to this implementation: https://github.com/Templarian/ui.bootstrap.contextMenu

The function to generate the context menu is passed three things:

- $cmScope - the scope of the context menu
- event - the event object that triggered the opening of the context menu
- modelValue - the value of the ng-model attached to the current object

So, in your example, you can use:

```
vm.menuOptions = function($cmScope, event, modelValue) = {
  var listArray = $scope.list; // array of possible list items based on ID 
  // ^ Assuming that the $scope here is the scope of the container, not the contextmenu
  angular.forEach(listArray, function(value, key) {
    if (modelValue === value.id) {
      return [ 
        [value.id, function ($itemScope) { 
          return value.textName; 
        }],                 
      ]
    }
  }     
}
```